# What qualifies as a JSF or Richfaces "container" for the process attribute?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

**Edit** I think the process attribute must point to an element in the same a4j:form. You can skip to my answer below.

---

Reading the *Using process attribute* section of this [article](http://java.dzone.com/news/richfaces-region-partial-jsf) they mention that it can point to any container. **What tags qualify as a container for use of the process attribute?**
Some that I am specifically considering:

- a4j:form
- a4j:outputPanel
- a4j:region
- rich:dataTable
- rich:panel
- rich:modalPanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to point to a4j:region. It definitely works with h:panelGrid or rich:panel. I doubt h:form can be used as the control with process-attribute is already within a form and then you are pointing to another form.

h:dataTable might work if you have inputs inside.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do RichFaces, but it makes technically sense that it only works on components which accepts an `id` attribute **and** renders HTML to the client side. JS/Ajax should namely be able to get a handle of it in the HTML DOM tree in the client side by JS `document.getElementById()` function.

So, in theory it should work on all `<rich:xxx>` and `<h:xxx>` components since they all render HTML to the client side. Most of those `<a4j:xxx>` components are abstract and server-side only and doesn't necessarily render anything to the client side, so it won't work on any of them.

Answer (score 0):

This answer originally contained what I thought was my results from trying, but it was actually that I reorganized how my forms were layed out. I'm guessing that I just am not using the process attribute and it probably works on all of them, but needs to be in the same a4j:form as the element it is pointing at.